# Does mining use a lot of bandwidth?

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining, bandwidth

If I setup a mining rig, will this use a lot of internet bandwidth? Do you know how many MB per day would be required? Is there a difference for mining pools and solo mining?

Answer (score 10):

Solo mining requires running a full node, pool mining does not. Also, when solo mining, it will usually take much longer to find a block when compared to a pool. Pools do charge a fee, normally 1-2% of the block reward.

When pool mining on a Windows PC, I use less than 20 Mb/day download and less than 5 Mb/day upload. Solo mining will be more bandwidth intensive due to running a full node.

Comment: Note that with solo mining, there is no "marginal" bandwidth. In other words, the bandwidth used is strictly from the daemon, so if you are already running a node, solo mining is cheaper on the margin